What Is this circa 1930 German object: a toy set, a poster or something else?
I have a low resolution reproduction of an old photograph, the original unfortunately no longer exists. It was taken at Christmas, with a nativity scene in the foreground and a Christmas tree on the right side. On the left is a table with presents. What interests me is the object in the window sill with the peculiar woodcut design. (The highlighting around it was done by me to show what I mean.)

One guess is the object was a metal construction toy set, for a boy of age 8-15. But what throws me a bit is the expressionist design, which would be extremely unusual for toy boxes of that time. Also, the photo looks as if the object is quite flat. A heavy box in that position would be in danger of falling from the narrow sill. Maybe it is simply a poster? From context, I would size it at ca. 60cm ✕ 45cm.
The photo was taken probably between 1930 and 1939, in a town near Frankfurt am Main, Germany. The father of the family was a metal worker at the Frankfurt plant construction company Lurgi, a Catholic, and member of the Zentrumspartei and the Kolping family.
Google Lens came up completely empty with only the motive in such a low resolution. Can anyone identify this?

A possible lead I now found are two pins of the Christlicher Metallarbeiterverband, a Christian worker's union. One of them is not dated and shows three symbols: a cross, a hammer and a gearwheel. All three are present on the object in the picture. If you look hard at the left figure, his left hand is pointing down to an object in front of him that could be another wheel, but also some sort of shield. With a lot of imagination, the form in the middle could be interpreted as the triangular CMV logo on the other pin. The problem is that the pin is dated to the 1960s, and so far I found no evidence the union used this before 1933.
Compare a blow-up of the object with the two pins:


Why do you think it would be a toy box, or a gift, in the first place? I'd guess some kind of poster.

@DevSolar Its placement at a table with Christmas presents speaks for a gift. I seem to remember my father (the boy mentioned) had, decades later, some parts that might have com from such a set. And I have a hard time imagining my grandfather decorating a Christmas table with a motive that is not religious, unless it is on a gift. (That might be a holy cross at the top right, but a workman with a hammer and a gearwheel??)

I was guessing at something like Worker's Welfare Organisation (Arbeiterwohlfahrt, AWO) or something like that, but could not get search hits either.

It looks like the object is completely flat although it is in front of both the window glass and the window frame which together are not flat speaking against the idea of some kind of poster. However, it seems to end at the bottom at exactly the top end of the window frame, so if it is a solid box it is unclear what it is supposed to stand on.

it looks like the last part of the lettering is hyphenated with a short word possibly starting A and "-GESELLEWERK[???]" and I think "gesell" is "journeyman"?

@Yorik looks more like Gesellenverein or Gesellenvereine to me, but hard to tell.

@jan that would make more sense. I don't speak German

@Yorik Please be careful with reading letters. In the original image, their vertical resolution is 5-6 pixels.

Regarding your edit, I think that the CMV is a very good lead; the imagery would be absolutely appropriate. Perhaps contact them directly in writing and ask if they have some kind of historian who could confirm it.

Might be that your CMV union is a later offshoot of the DMV-Deutscher Metallarbeiter-Verband, which also used a gear as emblem.

@justCal No. CMV was formed 1899 as a reaction to a conflict about religion in the "Zentralverein der Former". The socialist members were opposing Christianity, and Franz Wieber left the organisation to found the CMV. Ten years later, he again was one of the spearheads against religious neutrality and for strictly Catholic unions...

...After WWI these conflicts leveled out, but I would not be suprised if my grandfather felt bound by the 1912 papal encyclica Singulari quadam, ordering that Catholics could only be members in a workers union, if they also were members of a "Arbeiterverein" lead by a priest, like the Kolping groups.

Looking at their commemorative brochure for their 30th anniversary (which would be around 1930 I think), it seems CMV had a rather different aesthetic: https://library.fes.de/pdf-files/bibliothek/bestand/yy-01393.pdf
